# Add @Autowired to DataSourceFactory

Tags: spring, tomcat, datasource

I have a spring lib jar and would like to import it to my custom `DataSourceFactory` in Tomcat.
Does anyone have a solution?

Here is my code:

```
public class SecureDataSourceFactory extends DataSourceFactory {

    @Autowired
    private EncryptionUtil encryptionUtil;

    @Override
    public DataSource createDataSource(Properties properties, Context context, boolean XA) throws Exception {       encryptionUtil.replacePassword(properties);

        return super.createDataSource(properties, context, XA);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? What bean/component/class instance are you trying to inject/autowire into your class `SecureDataSourceFactory `?

Comment: Is your `SecureDataSourceFactory` a Spring managed bean? I am guessing it is created by Tomcat.